# ASP.NET MVC IF condition in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a action result method in the conrtoller which returns a IList to my view. Now the Ilist returns set of rows from database. some of the columns in there are bit values. Now 
when i am displaying those rows , the bit values are being displayed as true and false. I need to check in a IF condition if the value is true then display Yes , else display no. I am getting an error saying  **Compiler Error Message:** CS0103: The name 'True' does not exist in the current context

```
<% if(Model.Count < 1)
           {%>
                   No User's Add Under You!
        <% } else {
            foreach (var item in Model) { %> 
           <tr>
           <td class="usertd"><%= Html.Encode(item.UserName) %> </td>
           <td class="usertd"><%= Html.Encode(item.Role) %></td>
           <td class="usertd"><%= Html.Encode(item.Email)%> </td>
           <td><% if (item.EmailDoc.Equals(True)) { %>
               Yes <% } else { %>
               No  <% } %>
           </td>
           <td class="usertd"><%= Html.Encode(item.EmailDoc)%></td>
           <td class="usertd"><%= Html.Encode(item.PrintDoc)%></td>
           <td class="usertd"><%= Html.Encode(item.DownloadDoc)%></td>
           <td class="usertd"><input type="button" value="Edit User"/></td>
           </tr>
            <% }
        } %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is [case sensitive](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/12/the-case-for-case-insensitivity.html) actually:

```
<% if (item.EmailDoc.Equals(true)) { %>
```

which of course could be simplified to:

```
<% if (item.EmailDoc) { %>
```

But if your `item.EmailDoc` property is a `string` you need to do string comparison (it doesn't really make sense in this case to be a string but anyway):

```
<% if (item.EmailDoc == "True")) { %>
```